# How to use boost::crc?

Tags: c++, boost, crc

I want to use boost::crc so that it works exactly like [PHP's crc32()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) function. I tried reading the [horrible documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/crc/crc.html) and many headaches later I haven't made any progress.

Apparently I have to do something like:

```
int GetCrc32(const string& my_string) {
    return crc_32 = boost::crc<bits, TruncPoly, InitRem, FinalXor,
                   ReflectIn, ReflectRem>(my_string.c_str(), my_string.length());
}
```

`bits` should be 32.. What the other things are is a mystery. A little help? ;)

Comment: You can also use this http://svn.abisource.com/wv/branches/release-version-0-7-12/crc32.c  and http://svn.abisource.com/wv/branches/release-version-0-7-12/crc32.h. I assume the algorithm is the same but the speed is way better than boost crc.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Dan Story and ergosys provided good answers (apparently I was looking in the wrong place, that's why the headaches) but while I'm at it I wanted to provide a copy&paste solution for the function in my question for future googlers:

```
#include <boost/crc.hpp>

uint32_t GetCrc32(const string& my_string) {
    boost::crc_32_type result;
    result.process_bytes(my_string.data(), my_string.length());
    return result.checksum();
}
```

Comment: IMHO the return type should be unsigned (e.g. std::uint32_t).

Comment: @AndreasFlorath, I completely agree! Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer to use it.

Answer (score 10):

You probably want to use the `crc_32_type` instead of using the crc template. The template is general and meant to accommodate a wide range of CRC designs using widely varying parameters, but they ship four built-in pre-configured CRC types for common usage, covering CRC16, CCITT, XMODEM and CRC32.

Answer (score 5):

The library includes predefined CRC engines.   I think the one you want is crc_32_type.  See this example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/crc/crc_example.cpp

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the predefined `crc_32_type`?

Answer (score 4):

On this page, find the particular 32-bit CRC you want, read off all the other parameters:
http://regregex.bbcmicro.net/crc-catalogue.htm